# error while running python 2.7 code for deepwalk

Tags: python-2.7

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import random
from io import open
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
from collections import Counter
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import logging

from deepwalk import graph
from deepwalk import walks as serialized_walks
from walks import WalksCorpus
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from deepwalk.skipgram import Skipgram
from six import text_type as unicode
from six import iteritems
from six.moves import range

import psutil
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
try:
    p.set_cpu_affinity(list(range(cpu_count())))
except AttributeError:
    try:
        p.cpu_affinity(list(range(cpu_count())))
    except AttributeError:
        pass

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGFORMAT = "%(asctime).19s %(levelname)s %(filename)s: %(lineno)s %(message)s"


def debug(type_, value, tb):
  if hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or not sys.stderr.isatty():
    sys.__excepthook__(type_, value, tb)
  else:
    import traceback
    import pdb
    traceback.print_exception(type_, value, tb)
    print(u"\n")
    pdb.pm()


def process(args):

  if args.format == "adjlist":
    G = graph.load_adjacencylist(args.input, undirected=args.undirected)
  elif args.format == "edgelist":
    G = graph.load_edgelist(args.input, undirected=args.undirected)
  elif args.format == "mat":
    G = graph.load_matfile(args.input, variable_name=args.matfile_variable_name, undirected=args.undirected)
  else:
    raise Exception("Unknown file format: '%s'.  Valid formats: 'adjlist', 'edgelist', 'mat'" % args.format)

  print("Number of nodes: {}".format(len(G.nodes())))

  num_walks = len(G.nodes()) * args.number_walks

  print("Number of walks: {}".format(num_walks))

  data_size = num_walks * args.walk_length

  print("Data size (walks*length): {}".format(data_size))

  if data_size < args.max_memory_data_size:
    print("Walking...")
    walks = graph.build_deepwalk_corpus(G, num_paths=args.number_walks,
                                        path_length=args.walk_length, alpha=0, rand=random.Random(args.seed))
    print("Training...")
    model = Word2Vec(walks, size=args.representation_size, window=args.window_size, min_count=0, sg=1, hs=1, workers=args.workers)
  else:
    print("Data size {} is larger than limit (max-memory-data-size: {}).  Dumping walks to disk.".format(data_size, args.max_memory_data_size))
    print("Walking...")

    walks_filebase = args.output + ".walks"
    walk_files = serialized_walks.write_walks_to_disk(G, walks_filebase, num_paths=args.number_walks,
                                         path_length=args.walk_length, alpha=0, rand=random.Random(args.seed),
                                         num_workers=args.workers)

    print("Counting vertex frequency...")
    if not args.vertex_freq_degree:
      vertex_counts = serialized_walks.count_textfiles(walk_files, args.workers)
    else:
      # use degree distribution for frequency in tree
      vertex_counts = G.degree(nodes=G.iterkeys())

    print("Training...")
    walks_corpus = serialized_walks.WalksCorpus(walk_files)
    model = Skipgram(sentences=walks_corpus, vocabulary_counts=vertex_counts,
                     size=args.representation_size,
                     window=args.window_size, min_count=0, trim_rule=None, workers=args.workers)

  model.wv.save_word2vec_format(args.output)


def main():
  parser = ArgumentParser("deepwalk",
                          formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
                          conflict_handler='resolve')

  parser.add_argument("--debug", dest="debug", action='store_true', default=False,
                      help="drop a debugger if an exception is raised.")

  parser.add_argument('--format', default='adjlist',
                      help='File format of input file')

  parser.add_argument('--input', nargs='?', required=True,
                      help='Input graph file')

  parser.add_argument("-l", "--log", dest="log", default="INFO",
                      help="log verbosity level")

  parser.add_argument('--matfile-variable-name', default='network',
                      help='variable name of adjacency matrix inside a .mat file.')

  parser.add_argument('--max-memory-data-size', default=1000000000, type=int,
                      help='Size to start dumping walks to disk, instead of keeping them in memory.')

  parser.add_argument('--number-walks', default=10, type=int,
                      help='Number of random walks to start at each node')

  parser.add_argument('--output', required=True,
                      help='Output representation file')

  parser.add_argument('--representation-size', default=64, type=int,
                      help='Number of latent dimensions to learn for each node.')

  parser.add_argument('--seed', default=0, type=int,
                      help='Seed for random walk generator.')

  parser.add_argument('--undirected', default=True, type=bool,
                      help='Treat graph as undirected.')

  parser.add_argument('--vertex-freq-degree', default=False, action='store_true',
                      help='Use vertex degree to estimate the frequency of nodes '
                           'in the random walks. This option is faster than '
                           'calculating the vocabulary.')

  parser.add_argument('--walk-length', default=40, type=int,
                      help='Length of the random walk started at each node')

  parser.add_argument('--window-size', default=5, type=int,
                      help='Window size of skipgram model.')

  parser.add_argument('--workers', default=1, type=int,
                      help='Number of parallel processes.')


  args = parser.parse_args()
  numeric_level = getattr(logging, args.log.upper(), None)
  logging.basicConfig(format=LOGFORMAT)
  logger.setLevel(numeric_level)

  if args.debug:
   sys.excepthook = debug

  process(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.exit(main())
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "**main**.py", line 165, in      sys.exit(main())   File "**main**.py", line 162, in main     process(args)   File "**main**.py", line 93, in process     walks_corpus = serialized_walks.WalksCorpus(walk_files) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WalksCorpus'

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Please post some code to go along with this example.  We will need to have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: code is availabe at this site: https://github.com/phanein/deepwalk

Comment: Is this the code you wrote that contains the error around your question? Or is this just the source code for deepwalk? We will need your code and again a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is just the source code for deepwalk.

Comment: Is the error in your code or theirs?

Comment: Im guessing since the error is in `File "main.py"` it is in the code you are running. Please post the code you are running.

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are importing `WalksCorpus` on its own from `walks` with `from walks import WalksCorpus`.  Then when you try to use `WalksCorpus` method you are looking for it with in `serialized_walks` which I assume does not have the `WalksCorpus` method in it.

Try changing this line.

```
walks_corpus = serialized_walks.WalksCorpus(walk_files)
```

To:

```
walks_corpus = WalksCorpus(walk_files)
```

Comment: I can try and help out with the other error message but you may need to first review on your own and then come up with a MCVE of it.